# Is there a way to control the axis that a force field applies force?

Tags: force-fields

Is there a way to control the axis that a "Force Field" applies force? I'm specifically trying to constrict the force to the x & y axis not the z axis using the "Force Field" on a Cell Fractured Object. More force in the green and much less in the blue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can constrain the spherical force of a field into a cone or a tube, but these are directional.

1. To achieve the equatorial emission you require I recommend placing a
   force field in the middle to distribute particles.
2. Then 2 more force fields above and below at the polar regions. They
   will repel the vertical emitted particles.

[image: opposing forces particles]

Note that in this demonstration I have turned off the initial Normal emission speed.